# Why are my ornamental chili plants turning brown?

Tags: diagnosis, chili

I have some ornamental chili plants and they started to make chili. However they started to turn brown in colour as shown in the pictures. They started to turn brown a couple of weeks ago but they haven't increased. Why do you think this is happening?  I water them regularly once every two days.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do these plants like calcium to help keep things from rotting?

Comment: Are the ends soft or is it just a color change?

Comment: It was just a colour change.

Comment: Is it kept indoors or outdoors? What sort of temperature and sun exposure do they get? They like well drained soil and no over watering. Once every two days might be too much watering. Always check that the soil is dry before watering.

Comment: I keep them outside and they have 3 hours of direct sun. The next day after I water them  soil is very dry that is why I water them every two days. In addition, if I don't water them every two days leaves turn yellow and close a bit (direction upwards).